# Migrating Options to ASPNET Core RC2

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a application built on ASPNET Core RC1, which is using string typed configuration Options, and I am trying to migrate to RC2.

But the following code is not working anymore:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

According to ASPNET Core docs, it was supposed to converted this way:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
```

But this is also not working. The only overload available for the Configure extensions method accepts only a Action as parameter, and I don't want to have to parse the entire configuration myself.

What would be the right way to migrate this code?

Comment: This isn't working for me either; and adding the ConfigurationExtensions package doesn't help.  I can reference (via Configuration in startup) the whole path (i.e. "MyOptions:SubKey:SubKey"), but using GetSection() on "MyOptions" returns a value of null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` package.

Comment: A comment helped me. See @Couch's comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/37293489/5426333 .It contains a link https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1193

Comment: Thanks, it was missing the package.

Comment: Wow i spent days trying to upgrade to RC2 (Identity Framework with EF6 doesnt yet work for RC2) https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements is a good page to follow for breaking changes between releases