# Asp.net core how to change Connection String at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core, connection-string

I have 2 databases created by a `migration`. When my project (Asp.net core 2.2) starts, it shows a `view` that contains a `dropdownlist` of database names. Now I want any database selected anytime to change the connection string to new database.

I can create 2 connection strings using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287427/get-multiple-connection-strings-in-appsettings-json-without-ef). But I can`t get it to change the connection string at run time.

How can I change connection string at runtime?

Comment: check this method we have incorporated in our repository to change connection string based on the tenant id https://github.com/Boriszn/DeviceManager.Api/blob/19fde1cbbad9a3b36c6b2674d5958fc1fcfcb8d3/src/DeviceManager.Api/Data/Management/ContextFactory.cs#L75

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa Thanks but i think your repository is incomprehensible to me

Comment: I think it depends on what method/class you're using to initiate your db connection. Some source code might help to show a couple steps of what your program is doing immediately after the connection is made. Based on the link I'm guessing you're not using Entity Framework, but what are you using?

Comment: See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816215/dynamically-change-connection-string-in-asp-net-core ,checking per request based on logic .